# Displaying Google Earth Historical Imagery in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth, historical-imagery

I am currently carrying out research aimed at showing the evolution of plant cover in urban areas. I opted for the calculation of the vegetation index from Sentinel2 type images that I would like to refine the results using the historical images from Google Earth.

With the new version of QGIS, is it now possible to display historical images from Google Earth knowing that the area of the study area is about 500km²?

Comment: How far back do you want to go? Landsat 4+ is now freely available and goes back to 1982... There are other sources that provide sporadic historical images - these might be available via your University Library?

Answer (score 1):

I think what best suits for you in this case is [Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com)

With GEE, you can calculate NDVI index, check temporal satellite images from several operators, such as Sentinel2 and Landsat.

I'm aware that you can use GEE with Python and R. [This is a very good tutorial playlist about GEE with Python on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGjpjh9IQ5I&list=PLAxJ4-o7ZoPccOFv1dCwvGI6TYnirRTg3). I think there might have an GEE plataform, but not sure how it works.